# jQuery prevAll not working properly on table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I made many researches about that topic but not getting any success.

**Issue**

When i am trying to do `rowspan` based on custom attribute `rowspanx` at that time it is not working properly.

**How i am making rowspan based on rowspanx?**

So i am trying to find previous elements and next elements with `prevAll` and `nextAll`

if i found `prevAll() > 1` than it should work but it is not working properly. it is working proper only once but not second time.

I m getting unexpected output. which is in code snippet.

My expected output like below.

[image: expected output]

**EDIT**

my logic is if current element `td` have `rowspanx==1` so query should check for its all `previous` or `next` element have `rowspanx == 2` if it is found `true` in any `siblings elements` than current `td` add `rowspan = 2`.

This is my logic but it is not working properly.

Need Help!

```js
$('table.overview-table tr').each(function()
{
 $($(this).find("*")).each(function(i)
 {
  if($(this).attr("rowspanx") == 1 && $(this).attr("rowspanx") != undefined && ($(this).prevAll().attr("rowspanx") > 1 || $(this).nextAll().attr("rowspanx") > 1)){
   $(this).attr("rowspan","2");
  }
 });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100" border="1" class="table overview-table">
   <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <th scope="row" class="" rowspan="2">10:00</th>
      <td class="orange white" rowspan="1" rowspanx="2" style="height: 20px;">test</td>
      <td class="grey white" rowspan="1" rowspanx="2" style="height: 20px;">test</td>
      <td class="orange" rowspan="1" rowspanx="1" style="height: 20px;"></td>
      <td class="orange" rowspan="1" rowspanx="1" style="height: 20px;"></td>
   </tr>
   <tr style="display: table-row;">
      <td class="orange fat" rowspan="1" rowspanx="1" style="height: 20px;"></td>
      <td class="grey fat" rowspan="1" rowspanx="1" style="height: 20px;"></td>
      </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you wrapping a jQuery object in another jQuery object? `$($(this).find("*"))`. Also, this `$(this).prevAll().attr("rowspanx")` does not make sense, as `.prevAll()` returns a **collection of DOM nodes** and their attributes cannot be accessed all at once.

Comment: @Terry So how can i achieve my expected output?

Comment: What is your exact cell spanning logic?: here in jquery script you coded if previous has attribute `rowspanx=2` then next cell do span over two rows. An OK, third cell has attribute `rowspanx=2` and fourth cell is spanned over two rows. Fifth not, because previous one does not have attribute `rowspanx=2'.

Comment: @sbrbot the actual cell spanning logic if i get `td rowspax == 1` and its any one previous element have `rowspanx > 1` than that `td` should have `rowspan=2`

Answer (score 0):

For the sake of simplicity the CSS classes are omitted:

```
<table width="100" border="1" id="table">
  <tr>
    <th rowspan="2">10:00</th>
    <td rowspan="1" rowspanx="2">test</td>
    <td rowspan="1" rowspanx="2">test</td>
    <td rowspan="1" rowspanx="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" rowspanx="1"></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td rowspan="1" rowspanx="1"></td>
    <td rowspan="1" rowspanx="1"></td>
  </tr>
</table>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
$('#table tr td').each(function()
{
  if($(this).attr("rowspanx")==1)
  {
    $(this).attr("rowspan","2");
  }
});
</script>
```

[Example of JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/sbrbot/vxwmdb86/)

Comment: Ok let me try this example

Comment: This code will result in table that you need but I'm not sure this is complete y<our row spanning logic. You did not explain the algorhythm when you want row spanning of cells through two rows. And as stated before in comment, you cannot use prevAll() but prev() since prevAll() returns a collection of tags (not previous tag). If you want to do something wil all previous (or next) tags, you have to loop through all of them.

Comment: No your login will not work because i have to find all previous or next elements if anyone have `rowspanx == 2` than current element should be `rowspan=2`